# Javascript .add(option) not working in cordova ios project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

https://jsfiddle.net/nuov0ajw/

Here is my fiddle code which I want to use in my `cordova` application but the execution of code breaks at line

> list2.add(option);

I am unable to figure that out it why as it works well on safari browser.
Is it true that the `cordova` application for `ios` user web view of safari when launched in `ios` devices?

```
choose: <input type="text" list="languages" id="input_box">
<label for="languages">
  <datalist id="languages">
    <select id = "add_records">

    </select>
  </datalist>
</label>
<button onclick="abc();">get</button>
```

and the java script goes here:

```
var i;
var options = ["ASB", "SDJC" ,"S SDBCS" ,"SJDCJS OPWNX"];
//var list_allrec = document.getElementById('mylist');

var list2 = document.getElementById('add_records');

options.forEach(function (item) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = item;
    list2.add(option);
});

//$('#get').on('click',abc);

function abc (){
    //alert("Inside getval();");
    var val1=$("#input_box").val();
    alert(val1);
}
```

also that I have included the file `datalist.polyfill.min.js` file which is available on github at: https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill

I have also tried it with new application as suggested in the answer

the html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Trial App</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                              alert("Inside document ready")

                              var aTags = ["anuj", "all", "ball", "one", "blackberry", "zathura","friends", "game of thrones", "sport"];

                              $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
                                                                source: aTags
                                                                });

                              $('#get').on('click', get);

                              function get() {
                              //alert("Inside getval();");
                              var val1 = $("#autocomplete").val();
                              alert("Value inside text box is: "+val1);
                              }

                              });
            </script>

    </head>
    <body>

            <h1>Trial App</h1>
            <input type='text' title='Tags' id='autocomplete' />

            <button id="get">get</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work, attaching a screenshot of the application

[The screenshot of the application in work here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuuFp.png)

Comment: jsfiddle contains error, have you try debugging ?

Comment: @Anuj.T what type of errors does jsfiddle contain? yes i have tried debugging in xcode but the execution fails at the line list2.add(option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code in $(document).ready() event

Here is updated fiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuov0ajw/16/)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuov0ajw/17/) with add method

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='autocomplete' />
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var aTags = ["anuj", "all", "ball", "one", "blackberry", "zathura","friends", "game of thrones", "sport"];

 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
     source: aTags
 });

});
```

**Edit 1**

just use the jquery autocomplete

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj7001/7fmcnuhz/).

**Edit 2**

**UPDATED FULL CODE**

Here is the whole html code with js code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>autocomplete demo</title>
</head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
  <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var aTags = ["anuj", "all", "ball", "one", "blackberry", "zathura", "friends", "game of thrones", "sport"];

      $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: aTags
      });


      $('#get').on('click', get);

      function get() {
        //alert("Inside getval();");
        var val1 = $("#autocomplete").val();
        alert("Value inside text box is: " + val1);
      }

    });

  </script>
<body>
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='autocomplete' />
<button id="get">get</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Just jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css you need to include..you can customise the css later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried the above solution, but it works well for android and windows platforms but not for iOS, unable to figure out why?

Comment: datalist tag is not supported in safari browser.. thats why it is not working in ios. so now what you want to actually achieve? coz we have to find other way around apart from datalist element.

Comment: data list works in safari if you include the file datalist.polyfill.min.js file which is available on Github at: https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill as mentioned in the question. The fiddle mentioned in the question works on safari browser

Comment: i just want to achieve auto-complete feature in ios as it works using datalist in android and windows (all browser except safari)

Comment: actually the js you mention is not supporting the newer safari version..its readme mention that it will work on safari 6...iphone 3gs had the safari version 6...iphone 4 had version 7.1. so i am sure u r testing in the latest iphone... which has latest version of safari... so datalist-polyfill. js dont have support for the latest safari version..

Comment: updated the answer... look at the fiddle.. just use the jquery autocomplete.

Comment: But it is working on my safari browser (version 11.0) on my mac but not on cordova iOS simulators

Comment: The updated jquery is working as expected in safari, will try in simulator and i hope should work and post the result here

Comment: nope it did't work, it just works well in all browsers but not in the Cordova iOS app

Comment: then your problem is  different..Bcoz this is core jquery. It is working on my side.. so may be there is something else that is breaking your app.

Comment: Exactly, it works well in all browsers but not in app! unable to figure out why?

Comment: tried with fresh application too, but it is not working. I have updated the question pls check

Comment: You just forgot to add jquery-ui.js in your html file updated my answer. i am using cdn, you can download and use it locally. updated my answer

Comment: yes i have used CDN in my application still it is not working!

Comment: Just add Jquery-ui-min.js after jquery.js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

This is the issue.

Comment: @KrishnaLahoti just copy paste my full html code it will work completly fine :)

Comment: yes thanks for that answer, now it works well in android but not in ios

Comment: now you hav to debug it... check the console output. what error it shows ?

Comment: thanks for the updated code, it now works well as i need it, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: happy to help :)